# Insert event in Google Calendar PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to create somthing, but it's not working.

I have a database with shifts in it

```
(Shift, Location, Start Time, End Time,...).
```

I've created a page to search these shifts en show them.

This gives a table with the shift and 3 links to `edit, delete, or book them`.

Booking them should add them to My Google Calendar. The Book link sends the ID to the Add_Event.php Google always tries to let me login time after time without sending anything. I'm desperate. It worked yesterday. Now it stopped working.

**search.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Zoeken</title>

</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
<div>
<strong>Dienst: </strong> <input type="text" name="Dienst" value="<?php echo $Dienst; ?>" /><br/>
<input type="submit" name="zoeken" value="Zoeken">
</div>

</form> 
<?php




if (isset($_POST['zoeken']))
{ 
include('connect-db.php');
$id = $_POST['id'];
$Locatie =  $_POST['Locatie'];
$Periode =  $_POST['Periode'];
$Dag =  $_POST['Dag'];
$Dienst =  $_POST['Dienst'];
// get results from database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WMC_DeLijn WHERE Dienst='$Dienst' ") 
    or die(mysql_error()); 
// display data in table
echo "<p><b>Alles</b> | <a href='search_paginated.php?page=1'>Pagina</a></p>"; 

echo "<h2>Resultaten:</h2><p>";
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Locatie</th><th>Periode</th><th>Dag</th>  <th>Dienst</th><th>Delen</th><th>Geleed</th><th>Start 1</th><th>Eind 1</th>  <th>Start 2</th><th>Eind 2</th><th>Lijnen</th></tr>";


   // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    // echo out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Locatie'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Periode'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Dag'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Dienst'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Delen'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Geleed'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Start1'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Eind1'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Start2'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Eind2'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">' . $row['Lijnen'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Bewerken</a></td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Verwijderen</a></td>';
    echo '<td align="center"><a href="Add_Event.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Afspraak maken</a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";   

 } }

    // close table>
    echo "</table>";
?>

<p><a href="new.php">Toevoegen</a> | <a href="search.php">Zoeken</a> | <a    href="search_lijnen.php">Zoeken op lijnnummer</a></p>
```

**Add_Event.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
 // connect to the database
 include('connect-db.php');
// get the 'id' value from the URL (if it exists), making sure that it is   valid (checing that it is numeric/larger than 0)
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)
    {
    // query db
         $id = $_GET['id'];
         $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM WMC_DeLijn WHERE id=$id")
         or die(mysql_error()); 
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
         // check that the 'id' matches up with a row in the databse
        if($row)
         {
        // get data from db
        $Locatie = $row['Locatie'];
        $Periode = $row['Periode'];
        $Dag = $row['Dag'];
        $Dienst = $row['Dienst'];
        $Delen = $row['Delen'];
        $Geleed = $row['Geleed'];
        $Start1 = $row['Start1'];
        $Eind1 = $row['Eind1'];
        $Start2 = $row['Start2'];
        $Eind2 = $row['Eind2'];
        $Lijnen = $row['Lijnen'];
         }
         else
         // if no match, display result
         {
         echo "No results!";
         }
     }   
else
    // if the 'id' in the URL isn't valid, or if there is no 'id' value,  display an error
    {
    echo 'Error!';
 }


require_once '/customers/0/c/6/wmc-corner.be/httpd.www/DeLijn/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '/customers/0/c/6/wmc-corner.be/httpd.www/DeLijn/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
session_start();
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName("Diensten Boeken");

$client->setClientId('xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com');

$client->setClientSecret('xxxx');

 $client->setRedirectUri('http://www.xxx.be/xxx/search.php');

$client->setDeveloperKey('AIzaSyCyEC7cIu7yJS6ao73yaFMszKwvsWGkvFc');

$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout']))

{

 unset($_SESSION['token']);

}



if (isset($_GET['code']))

{

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

 }



if (isset($_SESSION['token']))

{

 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);

}



if ($client->getAccessToken())

{

 $calList = $cal->calendarList->listCalendarList();



  // print_r(get_declared_classes()); //This will dump the data of all declared classes so you can see what you have to work with

  //print "<br/><br/>";



  if(isset($_POST['action']))

 {

$action = $_POST['action'];

if($action == "addCalEvent")

{
    //Text Variables
    $tBus="Bus:   ";
    $tLijnen="Lijnen:   ";
    $tDienst="Dienst   ";
    $tDienst1="/1";
    $tDienst2="/2";
    $plus="T";
    $title1 = $tDienst.$fDienst.$tDienst1;
    $title2 = $tDienst.$fDienst.$tDienst2;
    $timezone= ".000+02:00";
    //Post Variables
    $title =$_POST["title"] ;
    $desc = $_POST["desc"];
    $calID = $_POST["calID"];
    $locat = $_POST["locat"];
    $ffrom = $_POST["from"];
    $funtil = $_POST["until"];
    $fPeriode = $_POST["Periode"];
    $fDelen = $_POST["Delen"];
    $fDienst = $_POST["Dienst"];
    $fGeleed = $_POST["Geleed"];
    $fStart1 = $_POST["Start1"];
    $fEind1 = $_POST["Eind1"];
    $fStart2 = $_POST["Start2"];
    $fEind2 = $_POST["Eind2"];
    $fDag = $_POST["Dag"];
    $fLijnen = $_POST["Lijnen"];


    //Time Variables
    $from= $ffrom.$plus.$fStart1.$timezone;
    $until= $funtil.$plus.$fEind1.$timezone;
    $from1= $ffrom.$plus.$fStart2.$timezone;
    $until1= $funtil.$plus.$fEind2.$timezone;

   if($fDelen ='1')
   {
       //Set the Event data

    $event = new Google_Event(); //note in the API examples it calls Event(). Apparently, they changed it and didn't update examples.

    $event->setSummary($title);

    $event->setDescription($desc);

    $event->setLocation($locat);

    $start = new Google_EventDateTime();

    $start->setDateTime($from);

    $event->setStart($start);

    $end = new Google_EventDateTime();

    $end->setDateTime($until);

    $event->setEnd($end);

    $attendee1 = new Google_EventAttendee();

    $attendee1->setEmail('addenteeEmail');



    // ...

    //$attendees = array(dewit.lesley@gmail.com);

    //$event->attendees = $attendees;



    $createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('u4slarv7t1qn1fsblvfkdoct4c@group.calendar.google.com', $event);


   // echo $createdEvent->getId();

   }
   else
   {

    $event = new Google_Event(); //note in the API examples it calls Event(). Apparently, they changed it and didn't update examples.
    $event->setSummary($title1);
    $event->setDescription($desc);
    $event->setLocation($locat);
    $start = new Google_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime($from);
    $event->setStart($start);
    $end = new Google_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime($until);
    $event->setEnd($end);
    $attendee1 = new Google_EventAttendee();
    $attendee1->setEmail('addenteeEmail');

    $event1 = new Google_Event(); //note in the API examples it calls Event(). Apparently, they changed it and didn't update examples.
    $event1->setSummary($title2);
    $event1->setDescription($desc);
    $event1->setLocation($locat);
    $start = new Google_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime($from1);
    $event1->setStart($start);
    $end = new Google_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime($until1);
    $event->setEnd($end);
    $attendee1 = new Google_EventAttendee();
    $attendee1->setEmail('addenteeEmail');

    $createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('xxx@group.calendar.google.com', $event);


   // echo $createdEvent->getId();

   }



}

  }





  // This is the form

   print "<div style='width:100%;height:100%;'><div style='width:550px;height:550px;text-align:center;margin:200px auto;background-color:#f0ffff;border:1px solid black;'><div style='padding:50px;'><table>";

   print "<form action='Add_Event.php' method='POST'>";
   print "<tr><td>Title: </td><td><input type='text' name='title'value=' Dienst: $Dienst' id='title'></td></tr>";
   print "<tr><td>Omschrijving: </td><td><input type='text' name='desc'value=' Geleed: $Geleed  Lijnen: $Lijnen' id='title'></td></tr>";
   print "<tr><td>Dag: </td><td><input type='text' name='locat'value='Stelplaats : $Locatie' id='desc'></td></tr>";
  print "<tr><td>Periode: </td><td><input type='text' name='Periode' value='$Periode' id='locat'></td></tr>";
  print "<tr><td>Dag: </td><td><input type='text' name='Dag'value='$Dag' id='desc'></td></tr>";
  print "<tr><td>Dienst: </td><td><input type='text' name='Dienst' value='$Dienst' id='locat'></td></tr>";
  print "<tr><td>Delen: </td><td><input type='text' name='Delen' value='$Delen' id='locat'></td></tr>";
  print "<tr><td>Start1: </td><td><input type='text' name='Start1' value='$Start1' id='Start1'></td></tr>";
  print "<tr><td>Eind1: </td><td><input type='text' name='Eind1' value='$Eind1' id='Eind1'></td></tr>";
  print "<tr><td>Start2: </td><td><input type='text' name='Start2' value='$Start2' id='Eind1'></td></tr>";
  print "<tr><td>Eind2: </td><td><input type='text' name='Eind2' value='$Eind2' id='Eind1'></td></tr>";
  print "<tr><td>Geleed: </td><td><input type='text' name='Geleed'value='$Geleed' id='desc'></td></tr>";
  print "<tr><td>Lijnen: </td><td><input type='text' name='Lijnen'value='$Lijnen' id='desc'></td></tr>";

  print "<tr><td colspan='2'>Datum Formaat: JJJJ-MM-DDTHH</td></tr>";

  print "<tr><td>From: </td><td><input type='text' name='from' id='from'></td></tr>";

  print "<tr><td>To: </td><td><input type='text' name='until' id='until'></td></tr>";

  print "<input type='hidden' name='action' value='addCalEvent'>";

  print "<tr><td colspan='2'><div style='text-align:right;'><input type='submit' value='Submit'></div></td></tr>";

  print "</form>";

  print "</table></div></div></div>";



  //Dumps Calendar Data so you can see what you're working with

  //print "<h1>Calendar List</h1><pre>" . print_r($calList, true) . "</pre>";



  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

 }

 else

{

  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();

  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Verbind met Google!</a>";

}

?>
```

Comment: define not working? The way your code is written you are going to have to authenticate that code every time it runs.  are you getting an error from the insert?

Comment: In that table I have all fields and 3 extra fields. Edit, Delete and Book (to calendar. That is sent to Add_Event.php (Add_Event.php?id=xx). It sends the Id and than I need to authenticate. Afterwords I just get Add_Event.php?code=xxx (titlebar) and not the id anymore that is used in the rest of the Add_Event.php code. With the id sent to Add_Event.php I was able to create an event in my Googe Calendar, Time was lookedup in the database, also the Title and description. Without the Id looked for in serach.php, the code will not work.

Comment: Just need to know how I can send the ID to pass the oauth2. When Clicking on the result in the table of search.php, this link                           <a href="Add_Event.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Afspraak maken</a> the Id part is gone after oauth2.

Comment: you don't find it google sends it to you its in $_GET['code']

Comment: Isn't there a way to send a value towards the second file? The Google Code is working. Was just looking for a way to lookup database values  (Start Time, End Time, Title and description) and add these to the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do what I needed to do. I reworte the code, and I'm using my Google Service account. This fixed my problem for now.